# How can i make post category list visible in all page in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make category name visible in every page. so for that I passed category model to every view. But here it is visible only in category_view.html page only.
I want to make it visible everywhere as I am listing out category name in navbar.

so far I did this

> templates/navbar.html

```
<nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">
      {%for name in category_name %}
        {% for lst in post %}
          <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="{% url 'posts:categoryview' slug=name.slug %}">{{name}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    </nav>
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404,render_to_response
from .models import Post, Category

# Create your views here.

def posts_list(request):
    query_list = Post.objects.all()
    category_name = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        "title" : "Latest Post",
        "query_list": query_list,
        "category_name": category_name 
    }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)


def view_category(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    category_name = Category.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('category_view.html', {
        'category': category,
        'post': Post.objects.filter(category=category).values(),
        'category_name': category_name
    })
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", posts_list, name="list"),
    path("<slug>", view_category, name="categoryview"),

]
```

Comment: use context_processor in Django, its made for the same purpose

Comment: @AjayGupta i have no idea about this,  i need to learn this thanks for suggesting.